# How do I convert a Date request.getParameter to string?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

So this is my servlet codes. I'm tryna add the user input to mysql.
AddEventsServlet.java:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doGet(request, response);
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String eventDesc= request.getParameter("eventDesc");
    <!--Here is my problem, it can't compile cuz Date StartTime and EndTime and Double budget is wrong -->

    Date StartTime= request.getParameter("StartTime");
    Date EndTime= request.getParameter("EndTime");

    Double Budget= request.getParameter("Budget");
}
```

I saw somewhere that request.getParameter is only for String so how do I convert it to String? Help please :)

Comment: `request.getParameter()` always returns primitive string. You need to convert your required format `(Date/Double/Integer etc)` after catching it from string format. Before converting you should check if the string is not null, otherwise you'll get a `NullpointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert string to date format

```
String StartTimeStr = request.getParameter("StartTime");
String EndTimeStr = request.getParameter("EndTime");

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date StartTime = dateFormat.parse(StartTimeStr);
Date EndTime = dateFormat.parse(EndTimeStr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) No error now for that line. How about this one-    Double Budget= request.getParameter("Budget");

Comment: Just add ... 
Double Budget= Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("Budget"));